# What does it mean " The request Url /index.bundle was not found on this server"?

Tags: url, error-handling, tags, react-native

When I run a react-native project, I get this error[image], but I don't know what mistakes I do, I was very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- click on `ctrl+M` and open settings .
- go to debug source host & port for device  and set the local host as `localhost:9090`
- now run the project

  ```
  react-native start --port 9090
  react-native run-android --port 9090
  ```